# Extend view with decorators

Tags: ruby-on-rails, wicked-pdf

I am using a ActiveJob object to generate a PDF with wicked_pdf. To do this I need to extend some view things to be able to do this is from a Job object:

```
view = ActionView::Base.new(ActionController::Base.view_paths, {})
view.extend(ApplicationHelper)
view.extend(Rails.application.routes.url_helpers)
view.extend(Rails.application.routes.url_helpers)
```

This is all working fine, the PDF is created. But in the view I use decorators like this:

```
- decorate invoice do |decorates|
  = decorates.title
```

And that is not working, probably because the object is not aware of these decorators, which are just PORO objects. So I guess I need to extend them too so they can be used here. How can I extend them? They are located in `app\decorators`

Edit:
The `decorates` method comes from a helper method:

```
module ApplicationHelper
  def decorate(object, klass = nil)
    unless object.nil?
      klass ||= "#{object.class}Decorator".constantize
      decorator = klass.new(object, self)
      yield decorator if block_given?
      decorator
    end
  end
end
```

And that helper method loads the correct decorator object:

```
class InvoiceDecorator < BaseDecorator
  decorates :invoice
end
```

Which inherits from Base decorator:

```
class BaseDecorator
  def initialize(object, template)
    @object = object
    @template = template
  end

  def self.decorates(name)
    define_method(name) do
      @object
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: What is origin of `decorate` method in view? It is from gem, or it is a helper_method?

Comment: Edited post to clarify the decorates method

Comment: What error exactly you recieved? Your code seems to be correct. ActiveJob executes in rails env, so it can access your decorators.

Comment: Oh, and just to be sure - your had added your decorators path to autoload, right?

Comment: There is no real error, but the PDF is empty. When I do it without any decorator, the PDF contains the expected content. Anything under `app/` is automatically loaded I think, but I added it anyway to try, but with the same empty PDF.

Comment: So, if it don't throw error, your decorators are loaded and problem somewhere else. Please, add your job here.